# How can I create a DB2 Full Text Index through SQL?

Tags: sql, db2, full-text-search

I'd like to create a full-text index on DB2 through SQL, I want to run it remotely as I won't have access to the server but I've run into a few problems.

I don't have control over the casing of the schema, so the following:

`CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_CREATE('my_schema_name', 'my_index_name', 'my_table (my_column)', '', 'en_us', ?)`

Won't work as it interprets 'my_schema_name' as MY_SCHEMA_NAME. I've tried using:

`'"my_schema_name"'` but this throws an error:

`The command failed because of an unexpected token. Un"`

I understand good/bad practice with schema/object names, but it needs to support lowercase schema names, and every other thing seems to work.

Comment: What exactly is the unexpected token? How do you issue the CALL statement? From a tool, from a program in a programming language, ...?

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?

Comment: Did you try just double quotes? `"my_schema_name"`

Comment: I'm issuing the CALL statement from DBeaver for testing, but I will eventually be calling it from .Net code. This is Db2 11.5 on Windows. I've tried ```"my_schema_name"```, but I get ```"my_schema_name"``` is not valid in the context where it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the schema in the table name:

`CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_CREATE('my_schema_name', 'my_index_name', 'my_schema_name.my_table (my_column)', '', 'en_us', ?)`

Works as expected.